# Scala SWT project with SBT

Tags: scala, swt, sbt

How do you create Scala SWT project in SBT?

I know that you can use GIT repositories:

```
RootProject(uri("http://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.binaries.git"))
```

But I don't know how and if it is possible with SWT.

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

**EDIT**:

I had to download it manually. It compiles but while running I get Invalid thread access error:

```
***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions.
[error] (run-main) org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
```

Even if I use:

```
javaOptions := Seq("-XstartOnFirstThread", "-d64")
```

This is the main class:

```
import org.eclipse.swt._
import org.eclipse.swt.layout._
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets._

object Main extends App {
    val display = new Display
    val shell = new Shell(display)
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout())
    shell.pack
    shell.open
    while (!shell.isDisposed) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch)
            display.sleep
    }
    display.dispose
}
```

Thanks again,
Etam.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 10):

Add this to your `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "swt-repo" at "http://maven-eclipse.github.io/maven"

libraryDependencies += {
  val os = (sys.props("os.name"), sys.props("os.arch")) match {
    case ("Linux", _) => "gtk.linux.x86"
    case ("Mac OS X", "amd64" | "x86_64") => "cocoa.macosx.x86_64"
    case ("Mac OS X", _) => "cocoa.macosx.x86"
    case (os, "amd64") if os.startsWith("Windows") => "win32.win32.x86_64"
    case (os, _) if os.startsWith("Windows") => "win32.win32.x86"
    case (os, arch) => sys.error("Cannot obtain lib for OS '" + os + "' and architecture '" + arch + "'")
  }
  val artifact = "org.eclipse.swt." + os
  "org.eclipse.swt" % artifact % "4.6.1"
}
```

It will first add a resolver for the SWT artifact repository.
It will then detect your OS version and download an appropriate JAR for it.

As for the thread access problem, I solved this on Mac OS X by using JDK 1.6 with it - when I specify `-XstartOnFirstThread` there, it works fine. I've found no solution for JDK 1.7.

Comment: Can you please tell me how should I set the right JDK version?
When `sbt` starts I get this message `Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_35).` but it still does not work for me.

I added the dependency you suggested and set `javaOptions := Seq("-XstartOnFirstThread", "-d64")`.

Comment: I usually do it on the bash level, I have a script that does this for me:       `JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home`
    `JDK_HOME=$JAVA_HOME`
    `PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`, so when `sbt` runs it picks up the default Java from the `PATH`.

Comment: However, you appear to be using java 1.6 already. Not sure, but it's possible that the `-XstartOnFirstThread` is not picked up from `javaOptions`. I usually run my application separately via script, and not through sbt, so I didn't have this problem. Where do you set `javaOptions`, `build.sbt` or in the `project` dir?

Comment: Btw, you could maybe add `-Dsome.property=someValue` and then print the contents of `sys.props("some.property")` to see if these flags even get picked up when you run your application.

Comment: In fact even exporting the environmental variables does not fix my issue. I set it in `build.sbt`

Comment: I added `javaOptions += "-Dsome.property=someValue"` to my `build.sbt` file. The I ran `sbt console` and finally executed `sys.props("some.property")` and it returned `res0: String = null`. It seems it does not pick options

Comment: Did you try removing the `-d64` flag?

Comment: Well, seems to me that the `javaOptions` could only be picked up by tasks starting a new JVM instance. I don't think `sbt console` does that - I think the console is started in the same JVM instance as sbt.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16924/discussion-between-mariosangiorgio-and-axel22)

Comment: Thanks for the code. My question is, I want to be able to build a jar for a different platform than the one I'm running sbt on.

Comment: You could set up your SBT build to download dependencies for all the platforms and pack all the different native libraries within the JAR. Then an appropriate native library will be used on each platform.

Answer (score 6):

I think the easiest way is download SWT jar file of your target platform, put it under `lib/` folder, and it will work fine.

Comment: Now I have a problem with invalid thread access error... Could you look at my edit?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same thread access error you did.  It seems to come from sbt launching your application as sub-process in the same JVM as sbt itself is running.

I solved it by building a jar, and then running my application manually:

```
scala -classpath "target/scala-2.9.1/foobar-0.0.1.jar:lib/swt-debug.jar" -J"-XstartOnFirstThread" foo.bar.HelloWorld
```

There might be a more elegant solution, but this at least got me as far as being able to run my application.